# How do I store images correctly in Redis?

Tags: php, redis

Decided to store images in Redis, how to do it correctly? Now I do this:

```
$redis->set('image_path', 'here is the base64 image code');
```

I'm not sure this is normal.

Comment: I mean, that'll probably work, but *why*? Base64ing the image will add 33% file size, and RAM is a lot more expensive than disk storage.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I'm parsing one site with a lot of images. So I want to store images somewhere so that I don't have to make constant requests to them. Are you thinking of using file storage?

Comment: Yes, a file-based cache would likely be much better in a variety of ways.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thank you very much for your help. Make out a response so that I can accept it and your reputation will improve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is perfectly ok to store images in Redis. Redis keys and values are both binary-safe

> Redis Strings are binary safe, this means that a Redis string can
> contain any kind of data, for instance a JPEG image or a serialized
> Ruby object.
>
> A String value can be at max 512 Megabytes in length.

See [Data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#:%7E:text=Redis%20Strings%20are%20binary%20safe,max%20512%20Megabytes%20in%20length.)

You can store the image in binary instead of base64 and it will be more efficient:

- In RAM memory usage on your redis server
- In Network usage
- In compute (CPU) usage assuming you are passing the images in binary to the final client

You can do

`$client->set('profile_picture', file_get_contents("profile.png"));`

See [Storing Binary Data in Redis](http://qnimate.com/storing-binary-data-in-redis/)

Comment: What's the best for img storage? In the cloud and retrieve via cdn or in Redis?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my simple example of storing image file into Redis Database and retrieve them as well

```
from PIL import Image
import redis
from io import BytesIO


output = BytesIO()
im = Image.open("/home/user/im.jpg")
im.save(output, format=im.format)

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port= 6379, db =0)
r.set('imgdata', output.getvalue())
output.close()
r.save  #redis-cli --raw get 'imgdata' >test.jpg
```

Comment: OP is using php